# Minecraft crashing everytime I try to launch Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, java, opengl, minecraft

Here is the error message exactly as I receive it, every single time I try to launch Minecraft. It was working fine a few months ago, and since this problem has started I have reinstalled minecraft and even gone through the manual install route with terminal.

Any thoughts on a good solution to this problem?

Thanks.

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I'm sorry, Dave.

Time: 8/25/18 1:26 PM
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to locate library: liblwjgl32.so
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:147)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:67)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:50)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.<init>(MemoryStack.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.create(MemoryStack.java:82)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.create(MemoryStack.java:71)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:284)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.stackGet(MemoryStack.java:628)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.stackPush(MemoryStack.java:637)
    at cgc.a(SourceFile:127)
    at cfs.an(SourceFile:557)
    at cfs.am(SourceFile:436)
    at cfs.a(SourceFile:380)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:144)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:147)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:67)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:50)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.<init>(MemoryStack.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.create(MemoryStack.java:82)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.create(MemoryStack.java:71)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:284)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.stackGet(MemoryStack.java:628)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.stackPush(MemoryStack.java:637)
    at cgc.a(SourceFile:127)
    at cfs.an(SourceFile:557)
    at cfs.am(SourceFile:436)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at cfs.a(SourceFile:380)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:144)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.13.1
    Operating System: Linux (i386) version 4.4.0-133-generic
    Java Version: 1.8.0_181, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 8856336 bytes (8 MB) / 174866432 bytes (166 MB) up to 523501568 bytes (499 MB)
    JVM Flags: 5 total; -Xmx512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    Launched Version: 1.13.1
    LWJGL: 3.1.6 build 14
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.lwjgl.system.Library
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Minecraft 1.13 [doesn't support](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/8bujfe/psa_minecraft_113_wont_run_on_x86_linux_machines/) 32-bit machines any more; since your machine is 32-bit (`i386`), you can't run Minecraft 1.13.

If your computer is actually 64-bit capable, but it's just running a 32-bit operating system, you could reinstall a 64-bit operating system. Otherwise, there's no way you can run Minecraft 1.13+, unfortunately.